# Type checking against dynamically created objects

Tags: python, abstract-class, typechecking

I want to perform some dynamic type checking for the inputs and outputs of a method. The solution that I've came up with is as follows. Basically, in the `__init__` function of the superclass, I update the subclass method with some dynamic type checking for both input and output. Note that, the type-checking should be based on the attributes (`AlgorithmAttribute`) that user defined during instantiation. I wonder if there is any better solution out there.

```
import abc
import six
import attr
from typing import Dict, Text

@attr.s
class AlgorithmAttribute(object):
  inputs = attr.ib(type=Dict[Text, int])
  outputs = attr.ib(type=Dict[Text, int])

class BaseHandler(six.with_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta, object)):
  def __init__(self, alg):
    self.alg = alg
    self.out = self.__getattribute__('prepare')
    self.__setattr__('prepare', self.temp)

  def temp(self, a, b):
    result = self.out(a, b)
    # Verifies inputs.
    if set(a.keys()) == set(self.alg.inputs.keys()):
      print('Inputs correct!')
    # Verifies outputs.
    if set(result.keys()) == set(self.alg.outputs.keys()):
      print('Outputs correct!')
    return result

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def prepare(self, a):
    pass


class SubHandler(BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self, alg):
      super(SubHandler, self).__init__(alg)

    def prepare(self, a:Dict[Text, int], b:Dict[Text, int]) -> Dict[Text, int]:
        return {'c': 33}


alg = AlgorithmAttribute(inputs={'a': 2, 'b': 3}, outputs={'c': 10})
sh = SubHandler(alg)
sh.prepare({'a': 20, 'b': 200}, b={'c': 20, 'd': 200})
```

Comment: A couple things, Amir, to help get your question answered. 1) Get rid of all code that isn't essential to the question. It makes it too hard for readers to quickly digest. 2) Tell us what is not right about the code you have now?

Comment: Thanks Steve for the comment. (1) While it is good to condense the code as much as possible, but I prefer to add the snippet in a way that it is easily executable by just a simple copy and paste. (2) I asked that if there is any better solution than this. A more Pytonic way?

Comment: I agree that executable examples are good, but it's also very helpful to introduce the code by quoting the interesting bits before dumping the full code on the reader...

Comment: Thanks @Nickolay. Will add more inline commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear to me why you validate the first argument of `prepare()` against `inputs` or what's the point of passing a dict with unused values to `AlgorithmAttribute`, but a more Pythonic way, in my opinion, would be to ditch the classes and use a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, Text

@dataclass
class AlgorithmAttribute(object):
    inputs: Dict[Text, int]
    outputs: Dict[Text, int]

def validate_inputs_outputs(validation_params: AlgorithmAttribute):
    def wrap(func):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            # Verifies inputs.
            if set(args[0].keys()) == set(validation_params.inputs.keys()):
                print('Inputs correct!')
            # Verifies outputs.
            if set(result.keys()) == set(validation_params.outputs.keys()):
                print('Outputs correct!')
            return result
        return wrapped_func
    return wrap

@validate_inputs_outputs(AlgorithmAttribute(inputs={'a': 2, 'b': 3}, outputs={'c': 10}))
def prepare(a:Dict[Text, int], b:Dict[Text, int]) -> Dict[Text, int]:
    return {'c': 33}

prepare({'a': 20, 'b': 200}, b={'c': 20, 'd': 200})
```

Comment: That's great. I think using the decorator makes the code easier to follow.